# Get parent from children in Django

Tags: django-models

I have two models in my models.py:

```
class Case(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Work(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    case = models.ForeignKey('Case', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my views.py I have function to update a work but also I need to access to its case to return to case template with POST:

```
def updateWork(request, pk):
work = Work(id=pk)
work_form = WorkForm(instance=work)
case = Work.objects.filter(...)

if request.method == 'POST':
    work_form = WorkForm(request.POST, instance=work)
    if work_form.is_valid():
        work_form.save()
        return redirect('update_case', pk='here should be the case id')

context = {'work_form': work_form, 'work': work}
return render(request, 'case/update_work.html', context)
```

How can I define the parent case id  of the specific work to point it in line: return redirect('update_case', pk='here should be the case id') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this through the `.case` attribute, or you can use `.case_id` to obtain the value for the column the `ForeignKey` refers to, which will be loaded when you need this:

```
def updateWork(request, pk):
    work = Work(id=pk)
    work_form = WorkForm(instance=work)
    case = Work.objects.filter(...)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        work_form = WorkForm(request.POST, instance=work)
        if work_form.is_valid():
            work_form.save()
            return redirect('update_case', pk=work.case_id)
    context = {'work_form': work_form, 'work': work, 'case': case}
    return render(request, 'case/update_work.html', context)
```

Comment: I tried it and got an error: "case.models.Work.case.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Work has no case."

Comment: @Oleh: Is this a `ForeignKey`? It looks at first sight that you have a `Case`  object that has a `OneToOneFIeld` to `Work`. Given it is a `ForeignKey`, is it nullable (with `null=True`)?

Comment: I think it is "a one to many relation": a case could have many works but work has one case. I didn't define null=True in my models.

Comment: @Oleh: if you go **from** `Work` to **`Case`**, it is a many-to-one relation. A `ForeignKey`, means that *many* `Work`s can refer to the *same* `Case`. But based on your comment it looks like you did some slightly different modeling than the case you show here.

Comment: @Oleh: if you have a `Work` object, you can use `mywork.case_id = 1425`, with `1425` the id of the case, given of course that `case = ...` a `ForeignKey` defined in the *`Work`* model.

Comment: thank - return redirect('update_case', pk=work.case_id) - is working. Thank you again.